# How to get a particular url using JQuery ..?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to identify each html page separately to add active style like(.select). But I'm not sure how to get a page url in using JQuery..?

for example I want to give .select class to about.html page when someone going to click the about button.

Please help me, im looking forward to your valuable replies.

Thanks
Paulson

Comment: Can you give more detail?  Your question is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to maintain a different css stylesheet for each page, but if you have to do it dynamically.

```
document.location.href
```

Is the standard way to ge the URL, and is not jQuery specific.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use JavaScript to get the specific page? What I usually do is set a page variable on each page load. If you need to pass it through to the JavaScript/jQuery you cold then just create a new variable inside of a  tag. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var page = location.pathname;

$('a[href$=' + page + ']').addClass('select');
```

This gets [the pathname portion of the URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), then uses the [attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with/) selector to find `<a>` elements that that have an `href` attribute that ends with the current path, and  [the `.addClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add the `select` class.